# find duplicates in different columns of a file

Tags: awk, gawk

The nature of my input is as follows

```
1234jjj hdhyvb 1234jjj
6789mmm mddyss skjhude
khora77 koemm  sado666
nn1004  nn1004 457fffy
```

I want to remove a row provided there are duplicates in the columns, for example in the first and last row there are duplicates, hence removed in the output

```
6789mmm mddyss skjhude
khora77 koemm  sado666
```

I tried

```
awk '$1!=$2 || $1!=$3 { print $0 }'
```

but it did not work

Answer (score 4):

This awk one-liner does it:

```
awk '{delete a;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]}length(a)==NF' file
```

With your example as input, it outputs:

```
6789mmm mddyss skjhude
khora77 koemm  sado666
```

It builds a hashtable (awk array), key is each field in a row. Finally we compare the size of the hashtable, if it is same as the number of field, we know that there is no duplicates, then print it out.

It works too if your file had 100 columns, you don't have to do `$1==$2 || .....$1==$100` check.

Comment: `^` for an elegant usage, was struggling with a loop till `NF`

Comment: for performance picker, we can check if there is already existed key in hashtable within the loop, if the file had big number of columns and rows, this way could be faster. however I think for normal use case, the posted answer is sufficient . @Inian

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example you can do something simple like this:

```
awk ' $1 != $2 && $1 != $3 && $2 != $3 ' input.txt
```

Output:

```
6789mmm mddyss skjhude
khora77 koemm  sado666
```

Comment: Not a generic solution! doesn't scale for more than 3 columns!

Comment: @Inian YAGNI, I didn't see in the question that he wanted something generic.

Comment: @dood your codes can be written in this way:  `awk '$1 != $2 && $1 != $3 && $2 != $3' file`

Answer (score 0):

Go thru every field and increment counter. Skip to `next` record if there was a match on the record. Otherwise `print`:

```
$ awk '{ delete a; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(++a[$i]>1) next; print }' foo
6789mmm mddyss skjhude
khora77 koemm  sado666
```

EDIT: Apparently quite identical to @Kent's solution but mine may be a tad more efficient. :D

EDIT2: ... and apparently he mentiones a speed-up in his comments...